# telegram android build error assembleAfatDebugTgVoipDex FAILED

Tags: android, telegram

I'm trying to building my Android application but I'm getting the following error:

```
Task :TMessagesProj:assembleAfatDebugTgVoipDex FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':TMessagesProj:assembleAfatDebugTgVoipDex'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/build-tools/30.0.1/dx''
```

my app is telegram

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error you should edit your build.gradle file under src folder.
Replace

```
def dxUtilPath = "${sdkDirectory.path}/build-tools/${buildToolsVersion}/dx"
```

with

```
def dxUtilPath = "${sdkDirectory.path}/build-tools/${buildToolsVersion}/dx.bat"
```

It will solve your problem.

Comment: thanks ,but after change it ,android studio show this error  Execution failed for task ':TMessagesProj:assembleAfatDebugTgVoipDex'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\bin\javac''